# Is this proof of the Archimedean Property valid?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

> Archimedean property: The set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ is not bounded above.

***Proof*** :

Suppose $\mathbb{N}$ is bounded above. Then, by the supremum property, there exits a lowest upper bound "$s$" for all $n \in\mathbb{N}$. Call "$k$" the biggest natural number, which is smaller than $s$. Then $k+1>s$ and since $k+1$ is a natural number, $s$ is not an upper bound of $\mathbb{N}$. Thus, we have reached a contradiction and can conclude that $\mathbb{N}$ is not bounded above.

Comment: No, finding k requires that N is unbounded.

Comment: @William Ellios, I don't see that. Can you go into a little more detail?

Comment: Having a supremum does not mean a maximum is ever achieved.  Example $(0,1)$ has a supremum.  But I can not then say "Call 'k' the biggest real number that is smaller than $\sup(0,1)$".  There is no such number and there is no reason to think there should be one.

Comment: "Bounded above" in $\mathbb N$ or in $\mathbb Q $ or in $\mathbb R$  or...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof works if and only if you have already proved

> For every real number $s>0$, the set $\{ n\in\mathbb N \mid n<s\} $ contains a largest element.

I don't know exactly which axiomatic facts abour $\mathbb R$ (and its relation to $\mathbb N$) you have available, so it *might* be possible for you to prove this without already having the Archimedean property. But it doesn't really sound *likely*.

---

(The proof suggested by William Elliot gets around this problem).

Comment: Thank you @Henning Makholm. That's what I wanted to understand.

Answer (score 18):

Assume N subset R is bounded above.
So there is a least upper bound of N.  Call it s.
If n in N, then n + 1 in N.  Hence n + 1 <= s, n <= s - 1.
Thus s - 1 is a smaller upper bound of N, a contradiction.

Comment: Cute way of putting it.  I've never seen that before.

Answer (score 0):

> "Call "k" the biggest natural number, which is smaller than s."

You have no reason to believe such a thing exists.

But you can prove it.

If $S \subset \mathbb N$ that is bounded above then $s \sup S$ exists.

Let $j = s-1$.  Then $j$ is not a upper bound of $S$.  So there exists a natural $k$ so that $j=s-1 < k \le s$.

Thus $s = j+1 < k+1 \le s+1$ and $k+1$ is not in $S$.  Nor are any natural numbers that are greater than $k$.  So $k$ is the greatest natural number in $S$.

So every upper bounded set of natural numbers will have a greatest element.

....

But this also proves that for any upper bounded set $S$ of natural numbers there exists natural numbers not in $S$ (namely all the natural numbers larger than $k$).

Thus we no longer have anything left to prove.  (No upper bound set of natural numbers contain all natural numbers, so $\mathbb N$ itself which *does* contain them all, can not be bounded above.)

.....

So actually, "every upper bounded set of natural numbers has a maximum element" and "the set of natural numbers are not bounded above" are equivalent statements both with the same proof.